# how to detect if user is logged in to site from another browser?

Tags: java, session, authentication

Scenario:

User logs into website.com using firefox. Login credentials are valid, user is directed to member's page.

User tries to log in to website.com using chrome. Login credentials are valid, because use is already logged in using firefox, system will throw error, asks user to close other session to login through chrome.

How can I detect that? Right now I am able to detect it if user only use one browser, but seems to break when user uses two different browsers to log in at different times.

EDIT* I want to say it's more than just using different browsers, the website should not allow multiple people to log in with the same login credentials.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming your application is j2EE/servlet based. If it is the case, two browsers are independent of each other, hence they have their own sessionId and can function independently, as long as your application does not interfere.

To prevent this scenario, one way to implement is, keep a hashmap of SessionID and UserID in your servlet. You populate this on every successful login, for example via a filter or a valve. When you are populating the hashmap, make a check, to see if any other sessionID is already using this userID. If it is used, check if the corresponding sessionID is still active. If it is not active, allow the login, and delete the stale sessionID. If it is active, terminate the other session and allow the login.

Answer (score 1):

In your application, keep a timeout of the user that's updated after each call to the app. You can define the user as 'locked' into a session (for example your firefox session) until either the timeout expires, or the user requests a logout. When you log in on another browse (for example, chrome) it checks to see if there's an active session and, if there is, denies the login attempt.

I'm going to make up a quick example. This isn't even close to production ready and is for illustrative purposes only.

```
class User {
    long lastCheckin;
    int userId;
    String username;
}
```

Now, when someone does anything in the app, like viewing a page, you do this

```
user.lastCheckin = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Now, when someone specifically requests a logout, you do this

```
user.lastCheckin = 0L;
```

Now, when someone tries to log in, you do this

```
if(user.lastCheckin + PREDEFINED_TIMEOUT > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    return new LoginResponse(false,"User is active in another session.");
}
```

Comment: hi, do you have any code snippet i can look at? i am not fully understand how to "lock" user into a session. thank you!

Comment: I've added some code that provides an idea of what I'm talking about. Clearly the values need to be persistent, and the LoginResponse object is something I made up, it doesn't really exist. It just gives you an idea.

Comment: ah, i see, i thought lock was some function i didnt know about. it think if i use this method id have to make changes to the db, which i dont think will happen because db people -.-!

Comment: You can persist it in memory if you want, you just have to make it thread-safe. A simple job every so often to eliminate old sessions should be running anyway. If you were to persist it in the database, you'd be adding only a single column - `lastCheckin`. It requires no index or anything, just 8 bytes of a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Security - it may be specified by  parameter in the configuration file.

If just plain java - during log-in put user's session id to some storage; when he tries to log-in again you should prohibit it.
But you need to avoid situation when the user will be in storage very long time after closing the browser (one possible solution is short session timeout + keep-alive requests)

Answer (score 1):

You can store a map of logged-in users on an application scope variable like a ServletContext. For example, on your auth servlet, you can probably do something like:

```
Map<String,String> activeUsers = request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("__ONLINE_AUTHENTICATED_USERS");
//if null, context hasn't been prepared yet, create and attach a new one?2
```

You have to be careful though. Being an application scope variable, you need to ensure some thread safety and this is something which the servletContext.setAttribute/getAttribute is providing(e.g. those operations are not thread safe). You may be able to handle this by using some sort of application lifecycle listener to 'initialize' the servletContext to have the user map. This way you won't need to worry about the set/getAttribute. You still need to think about the map operations themselves(e.g. use j.u.c.ConcurrentHashMap maybe?).

You also have to take care of cleaning up(e.g. removing from the map) when a user logs out or session times out.

You also have to consider that a user might lock himself out for a long time by this approach(e.g. close browser but do not logout properly, session needs to timeout before the mapping is cleared).

Edit:
You also need to think about scalability and this depends on your application. Are you expecting a million online users? Or only a couple of thousands?

Comment: looks risky lol, but i think it's probably better than to add some new fields to the db..

Comment: It is risky if you don't know what you are doing. A lot of frameworks use the servlet context to store application state.

Comment: ya, im still a noob, ill do some research on this before implementing though, thanks! as for users itll be prob <50k